# Tensorflow libraries and hidden imports not found when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to compile a code to run standalone. But when running the command `pyinstaller Sector_Risk_Prediction_Application.pyw` it throws many `WARNING`.I can only understand its related to tensorflow. The appilcation runs fine on my system but it shows error for tensorflow on other systems where python is not installed. The warnings are as follows:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.
collect_submodules: failed to import 'tensorflow.~ython'!
264285 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.efficientnet" not found!
264694 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.initializers" not found!
264697 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.xception" not found!
269811 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.metrics" not found!
269811 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.premade" not found!
269814 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.layers" not found!
269815 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_v3" not found!
269823 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.experimental" not found!
269823 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet" not found!
270075 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.vgg16" not found!
279137 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.legacy.layers" not found!
279137 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras" not found!
279171 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.__internal__.models" not found!
279171 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.sequence" not found!
279178 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers" not found!
279180 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.reuters" not found!
279942 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.efficientnet" not found!
279985 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.xception" not found!
279986 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.estimator.export" not found!
279991 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist" not found!
280107 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.nn.layers" not found!
280109 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers" not found!
280258 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.activations" not found!
280263 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.__internal__" not found!
280265 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision" not found!
280268 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision" not found!
280458 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.__internal__.models" not found!
280464 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2" not found!
280493 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.efficientnet" not found!
280509 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.__internal__" not found!
280510 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.callbacks.experimental" not found!
280513 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.mnist" not found!
280782 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16" not found!
280788 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.experimental" not found!
280791 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.boston_housing" not found!
280908 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.optimizers.schedules" not found!
280908 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.legacy.rnn_cell" not found!
280917 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.vgg16" not found!
280938 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist" not found!
280946 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.optimizers" not found!
281021 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers.experimental" not found!
281022 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.models" not found!
281024 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2" not found!
281223 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.sequence" not found!
281226 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.estimator" not found!
281229 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.v1" not found!
281235 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.rnn_cell" not found!
281237 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn" not found!
281241 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.sequence" not found!
281247 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist" not found!
281271 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.v2" not found!
281276 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.premade" not found!
281663 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.layers" not found!
281663 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.experimental" not found!
281746 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications" not found!
281752 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist" not found!
281777 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.__internal__.losses" not found!
281916 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn" not found!
281928 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.activations" not found!
282163 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet" not found!
282165 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.utils.experimental" not found!
282292 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet" not found!
282294 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.optimizers" not found!
282301 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.image" not found!
282305 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3" not found!
282307 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.utils" not found!
282307 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks.experimental" not found!
282314 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications" not found!
282321 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.text" not found!
282326 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras" not found!
282506 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets.reuters" not found!
283019 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2" not found!
283026 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.__internal__.backend" not found!
283028 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar10" not found!
283035 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets" not found!
283035 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.v1" not found!
283038 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16" not found!
283039 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.imagenet_utils" not found!
283040 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.mixed_precision" not found!
283226 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.estimator" not found!
283229 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.boston_housing" not found!
283232 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.losses" not found!
283394 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.callbacks.experimental" not found!
283712 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras" not found!
283716 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.losses" not found!
283717 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks.experimental" not found!
283750 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.regularizers" not found!
283879 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.imdb" not found!
283880 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.layers.experimental" not found!
283998 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2" not found!
284003 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.imagenet_utils" not found!
284011 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets" not found!
284013 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet_v2" not found!
284023 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg19" not found!
284025 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.cifar100" not found!
284026 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2" not found!
284050 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision.experimental" not found!
284051 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.boston_housing" not found!
284061 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets" not found!
284063 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing.sequence" not found!
284082 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.imagenet_utils" not found!
284179 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.__internal__.utils" not found!
284212 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.regularizers" not found!
284217 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.nasnet" not found!
284219 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.mixed_precision.experimental" not found!
284221 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.backend" not found!
284232 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.wrappers" not found!
284237 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets.imdb" not found!
284241 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.losses" not found!
284243 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.nasnet" not found!
284246 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.models" not found!
284411 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing" not found!
284416 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.experimental" not found!
284417 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras" not found!
284571 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.datasets" not found!
284586 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.efficientnet" not found!
284589 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.callbacks" not found!
284597 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets" not found!
284635 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.cifar10" not found!
284635 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet" not found!
284641 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks" not found!
284819 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.experimental" not found!
284827 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.mnist" not found!
284829 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications" not found!
284830 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3" not found!
284871 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.initializers" not found!
284878 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.experimental" not found!
284881 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50" not found!
284889 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_v3" not found!
285100 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.wrappers" not found!
285180 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.estimator" not found!
285192 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets.cifar100" not found!
285341 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.densenet" not found!
285348 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.datasets.boston_housing" not found!
285352 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.regularizers" not found!
285354 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.__internal__.utils" not found!
285388 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.estimator.experimental" not found!
285397 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg19" not found!
286333 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_v2" not found!
286335 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.estimator.experimental" not found!
286577 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.export" not found!
286585 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.vgg19" not found!
291719 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3" not found!
291802 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet" not found!
291812 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.constraints" not found!
291815 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.vgg19" not found!
291820 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.estimator.inputs" not found!
291868 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.reuters" not found!
291882 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.xception" not found!
291885 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.efficientnet" not found!
291922 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.initializers" not found!
```

I couldn't add all the hidden import warnings due to the limitation on characters. I assume its common.

The `Warning` for `lib not found are`:

```
324281 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\_pywrap_record_io.pyd
324353 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\experimental\pywrap_libexport.pyd
324463 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_item.pyd
324598 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_cluster.pyd
324629 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_nest.pyd
324698 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_events_writer.pyd
324802 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\service\_pywrap_server_lib.pyd
324873 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal\_pywrap_traceme.pyd
324993 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_op_def_registry.pyd
325085 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_tfprof.pyd
325185 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_optimizer.pyd
325238 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_checkpoint_reader.pyd
325302 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_op_def_util.pyd
325368 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\_pywrap_file_io.pyd
325451 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_parameter_converter.pyd
325511 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_transform_graph.pyd
325888 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_info.pyd
326021 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_tensor_float_32_execution.pyd
326062 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_stat_summarizer.pyd
326170 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_kernel_registry.pyd
326459 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_dispatcher.pyd
326534 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_tf_session.pyd
326627 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_op_gen.pyd
326669 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_device_lib.pyd
326727 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_debug_events_writer.pyd
326817 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal\_pywrap_profiler.pyd
326873 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_errors_test_helper.pyd
326923 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_dtypes.pyd
326972 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_utils.pyd
326986 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
327155 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\core\_pywrap_py_func.pyd
327171 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\core\_pywrap_bfloat16.pyd
327192 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\_pywrap_stacktrace_handler.pyd
```

I am not sure what can be done about this.

Secondly the final compiled `dist` folder is almost 6GB. Is there a way to make this significantly smaller in size?

Alternatively if I could create a setup file to install the required things on another system.

Answer (score 1):

I have had my own external library issues with pyinstaller too, one thing we need to accept as python programmers is python code is not meant to be in an executable file, you'll have to install python in a machine to be able to run it, the best way to manage your libraries is to write them in a **requirements.txt** file and run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the machine after installing python, for more info on requirements.txt check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html#apply_dependencies)

Comment: I made the ```requirements.txt``` file. I was wondering if I can use this without pycharm that you have given the link for. Also can I run this file anywhere in the system after installing windows will I need to go to the scripts folder in python38 in c drive to install this? I am asking this from a perspective of an employee who has no idea what this is and just wants to use the python code for his work.

Comment: yes you can use this without pycharm and no you should not run this file anywhere and no you don't have to enter the python38 folder. this file is now part of your project as it contains the names of the libraries your code depends on. on any machine with python installed, you'll open the command prompt or powershell and browse to the location of this file and run the command ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` this will install all the libraries you mentioned in there, with python and its necessary libraries installed your code should work the same on any foreign machine. I hope this helped